# How to get back to specific fragment of a activity from another activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In app I have a activity named as **Home** and in Home activity there are two fragments one is **AppointmentFragment** and the other is **ServiceFragment** and the AppointmentFragment is default fragment mean to say whenever Home Activity has been launched it open AppointmentFragment as its home page. 
Now ServiceFragment contains a button which opens a activity named as **ServiceDetails**.
here is the code in ServiceFragment

```
        add_services_button_updated.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.servicesfragment), "ServicesFragment");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now whenever i press back button in ServiceDetails Activity it takes me to the default fragment i.e. AppointmentFragment. I want to ask how to move on the ServiceFragment aur mean to say previous fragment on pressing back button in the activity.

Comment: Use startActivityForResult() instead and then in onActivityResult() go to the wanted fragment.

Comment: Thanks it is working